# Add radio buttons dynamically based on JList selection

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I want to add a bunch of radio buttons dynamically based on the categories a user selects in a JList. These in turn create different textboxes depending on selection, as below. I'm not sure how much to include in my ListSelectionListener anonymous inner class, and how to go about it.

From the selected category list, for each category:

- a radio button with 3 options
- if option 1 is selected, 3 textboxes to enter data
- if option 2 is selected, 1 textbox to enter data
- if option 3 selected, remove category from list

At the moment this is what I have. I'm also getting an error in this line of code:arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.get(1).addActionListener(this); regarding passing in 'this'. I am not sure what I am supposed to be passing in:

```
MyClass implements ActionListener{

ArrayList<ButtonGroup> arrayButtonGroupsCategories =  new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<JRadioButton> arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType = new ArrayList<>();

MyClass(final Container pane){
    preprocessPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,2,10,10));
    //other stuff
    categorySubPanel = new JPanel();
    preprocessPanel.add(categorySubPanel);
    preprocessPanel.setVisible(true);
    pane.add(preprocessPanel);
}

private void createCategoryInfoGUI() {
openFile();
categories = new JList<>(getColumnNames());
categories.setVisibleRowCount(5);     
categories.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
preprocessPanel.add(new JScrollPane(categories));
categories.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if(!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
            final List<String> selectedValuesList = categories.getSelectedValuesList();
            System.out.println(selectedValuesList);
        }
        int i = 0;
        for (String key: selectedValuesList){
            arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.add(new JRadioButton("Nominal"));
            arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.get(1).addActionListener(this);
            arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.add(new JRadioButton("Ordinal"));
            arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.add(new JRadioButton("Neither"));
            arrayButtonGroupsCategories.add(new ButtonGroup());
            arrayButtonGroupsCategories.get(i).add(arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.get(i));
            arrayButtonGroupsCategories.get(i+1).add(arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.get(i+1));
            arrayButtonGroupsCategories.get(i+2).add(arrayRadioButtonSubcategoriesType.get(i+2));
            i+=3;
        }
    }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) Please post a valid [mcve] program 2) please show your own attempt to add the JRadioButtons and tell us what problems you're having with your own attempt. Your code above does not show this. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: I have posted some code to add radio buttons. I have not been able to run it as it is producing an error as described when I try to add the action listener. I really haven't found any tutorials that discuss what I am trying to do, namely add buttons dynamically within a list, which is why I posted a question. If you know of any, I would appreciate the heads up.

Comment: Your `this` refers to the inner class. You need to name the outer class to obtain its this: `MyClass.this`

Comment: thank you, appreciate it

Comment: If you have self-solved this issue. Please post an educational answer and mark it "accepted" with the green tick.  If this question remains unresolved, please update your question (via edit) to express precisely what isn't working as desired.  All questions should progress to a system-recognized resolution.

Comment: I did self solve it but it was a while ago. When I get some time I'll go back through that project and post what I did.